# Why typescript doesn't report error for my param without types, even if I've specified noImplicitAny to true?

Tags: typescript, typechecking

This is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "files": [
    "server.ts"
  ]
}
```

You can see `noImplicitAny` is set to `true`.

And this is my `server.ts`:

```
import * as express from 'express';

const app = express();

app.get('/:name', (req, res) => {
  const name = req.params.name;
  res.send(`Hello, ${name}`);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listen on http://localhost:3000')
});
```

Please notice the part `(req, res)` has no types, but typescript doesn't give any error.

I'm not sure where is wrong and how to make typescript throw errors.

This is a small complete demo project for this question: https://github.com/freewind-demos/typescript-express-demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`noImplicitAny` throws an error if the type of a parameter or variable can't be inferred and would have to implicitly be typed as any.

If this case `req, res` are not typed as any. Since they are the parameters to a callback their type can be determined based on the callback type, and is inferred to `Request` and `Response` respectively.